# How can I find the solution around $r=1$ for this ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The ODE is

$$-B^{\prime\prime}r(r-1)+B^\prime+\left(\dfrac{1}{r}+\dfrac{r^3}{\exp(-r)}\right)B=0$$

where a prime indicates a derivative wrt $r$. I need to find the solution around $r=1$. The exponential blocks me, if it weren't there I could use Frobenius method.

How can I do it? Is it  a solution to expand the exponential around $r=1$?

Comment: Primes of $B$ are differentiation with respect to $r?$

Comment: @Narasimham Yes, I am sorry I will add this information

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+r%5E3%2Fexp%28-r%29+around+r%3D1

Comment: Around one, we could write the term $r-1=\epsilon$ r=1 physically speaking it is convenient for other terms, and make a Taylor development around $1$ for $B$. For more precision make Taylor of $r^3/\exp(-r)$

Comment: I second Claude's response. A series of $\exp(-r)$ about $r=1$ is probably the best option here.

Comment: @K.defaoite So I have to expand around 1 and then use the Frobenius method?

Comment: @mattiav27 seems like the best approach to me.